# How to modify the Task Name Column using JSLink in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, jslink

I am trying to modify the color of SharePoint 2013's Task Name column in a list using JSLink. I can override every other column using this code:

```
var overrideCtx = {
    Templates: {
        Fields: {
            ‘Title': {‘View’ : taskSample.TitleRendering },
            ‘PercentComplete': {‘View’ : taskSample.PercentCompleteRendering}
        }
    }
};
```

For some reason when I debug the code in Google Chrome the TitleRendering function is always skipped, while the PercentCompleteRendering function is executed fine.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Thanks

I have tried the suggestion of LinkTitle in the answers below; it did not resolve my issue. I am including all my code for review. Any other suggestions?

```js
var taskSample = taskSample || {};

taskSample.CustomizeFieldRendering = function () {
  RegisterSod('hierarchytaskslist.js', '/_layouts/15/hierarchytaskslist.js');
  LoadSodByKey('hierarchytaskslist.js', null);
debugger;
    // Intialize the variables for overrides objects
  var overrideCtx = {
    Templates: {
      Fields: {
   'Unit': { 
          'View' : taskSample.UnitRendering
        },
    'LinkTitle': { 
          'View' : taskSample.TitleRendering
        },
        'PercentComplete': { 
          'View' : taskSample.PercentCompleteRendering
        }  
      }
    }
  };

  // Register the override of the field
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}
taskSample.PercentCompleteRendering = function (ctx) {
debugger;
 var output = [];
 var _dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.DueDate);         
 var _now = new Date();    
 var nowPlus = new Date();    
 nowPlus.setDate(_now.getDate()+7);
 output.push('<div style="background: #dbdbdb; display:block; height: 20px; width: 150px;">');
 if ((_dueDate >= _now && _dueDate <= nowPlus)&& (ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") === "0") ) {   
     output.push('<span style="color: #dbc900; font-weight: bold; position:absolute; text-align: center; width: 150px;">');
  }     
 else if ((_dueDate < _now)&& (ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") === "0") ) {   
     output.push('<span style="color: #CC0000; font-weight: bold; position:absolute; text-align: center; width: 150px;">');
  }     
 else{
  output.push('<span style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; position:absolute; text-align: center; width: 150px;">'); 
 } 
 output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete);
 output.push('</span>');
 output.push('<div style="height: 100%; width: '); 
    if (_dueDate == 'Invalid Date') {   
      output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") + '%; background: #757575;');    //grey 
   }   
  else if (ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") === "100")      {       
   output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") + '%; background: #339900;'); //gree  
  }   
  else if (_dueDate < _now)     {       
   output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") + '%; background: #CC0000;'); //red   
  }         
  else if (_dueDate >= _now && _dueDate <= nowPlus)     {        
  output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") + '%; background: #dbc900;');  //yellow   
   }    
    else if (_dueDate > _now)     {        
  output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "") + '%; background: #339900;');  //green    
   }   
 output.push('"></div></div>');
 return output.join('');
}
taskSample.UnitRendering = function (ctx) {
debugger;
 var output = [];
 var _Unit = ctx.CurrentItem.Unit;
    switch(_Unit) {
      case "Unit 1":
          output.push('<span style="color: DarkMagenta;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
      case "Unit 2":
          output.push('<span style="color: DarkRed;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 3":
         output.push('<span style="color: MidnightBlue;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 4":
          output.push('<span style="color: DarkOliveGreen ;">');
     output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 5":
          output.push('<span style="color: GoldenRod;">');
     output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 6":
         output.push('<span style="color: Coral;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
      default:
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Unit);
         break;
   }  
 return output.join('');
}
taskSample.TitleRendering = function (ctx) {
debugger;
 var output = [];
 var _Unit = ctx.CurrentItem.Unit;  
  switch(_Unit) {
      case "Unit 1":
          output.push('<span style="color: DarkMagenta;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
      case "Unit 2":
          output.push('<span style="color: DarkRed;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 3":
         output.push('<span style="color: MidnightBlue;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 4":
          output.push('<span style="color: DarkOliveGreen ;">');
     output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 5":
          output.push('<span style="color: GoldenRod;">');
     output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
   case "Unit 6":
         output.push('<span style="color: Coral;">');
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
    output.push('</span>');
         break;
      default:
    output.push(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
         break;
  }  
 return output.join('');
 }
taskSample.CustomizeFieldRendering();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tasks default view `Task Name (linked to item with edit menu)` column is used by default for rendering task name. If so, then you should use `LinkTitle` internal name instead of `Title`.

**Example**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     Templates: {
        Fields: {
            'LinkTitle' : { 
                'View' : function(ctx){
                          var percentValue = ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete; 
                             if(percentValue == "100 %"){
                                 return String.format('<span style="background-color:#00ff00">{0}</span>',ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                             }
                             else {
                                 return String.format('<span>{0}</span>',percentValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                             }
                         } 
             }
        }
     }
   }); 

});
```

**Result**

[image]